# Catch cross domain response in pure javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to catch cross domain response in pure javascript ajax not using jquery or other external libraries.

```
var xmlhttp, response;

try {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} catch(e) { 

   try { 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e2) { 

       try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
    }
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) { 
        if(callback != undefined) { 
              console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
}

url = "http://xxxx.com/layer.php?callback=callRes";
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/json,application/javascript,text/javascript");
xmlhttp.send();
```

spent lots of time  and googling but not find any solution

suggestions are most welcome but not script method only pure javascript ajax

Comment: Should not be possible. The Same Origin Policy can only be avoided by the use of some Browser Plugins. Why not JSONP?

Comment: It would ***have*** to be JSONP.

Comment: as i mentioned in my question i want to use pure javascript ajax not script method

Comment: Where is the response coming from? Do you have access to adjust the headers? If so use CORS and adjust the headers to allow your front end code access. This can even be accomplished on S3 if the resource you're requesting is on there.

Comment: Do you have access to this file http://xxxx.com/layer.php ?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you can't do that. If they don't allow/provide a way to do it.

Comment: but i getting the callback response "response({"msg_arr":{"user_email":"Please enter valid email ID.","user_name":"Pick a bigger username. Atleast 5 characters.","user_country_code":"Country code required.","user_mobile_number":"Mobile number required."},"msg_type":"error"})" but unable to catch in variable

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to see the response in console.

Before calling `console.log()` you are checking to see if `callback` exists. In the given piece of code `callback` is not yet defined so maybe this is the only barrier preventing the output of `xmlhttp.responseText`.

Solution: remove `if (callback != undefined)` and just call `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)`

Comment: i'm trying this but unfortunately it not working

Comment: You get some error message? Add `console.log(xmlhttp.readyState)` at the beginning of the `onreadystatechange` function to see how far it goes.

Comment: getting response in network window but not catch